# how to implement image into autocomplete script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to add Image in auto complete script.
Here is my code, Please help to fix it.

**Here My Countroller is**

```
function getsearch($c_id)
{
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT state_name FROM state WHERE country_id = '".$c_id."' and state_name LIKE '".$searchTerm."%'");
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
    $data[] = $row['state_name'];
    }
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**My View as below**

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Location (E.g. Ontario)" class="sarbx ani-1" name="location" id="compnies_id">
```

**Java Script**

```js
function state_search()
{
$(function() {

var country = $('#countries').val();
var controller = 'directories/getsearch';

var url = '<? echo base_url();?>';
    $( "#compnies_id" ).autocomplete({
           source: url+''+controller+'/'+country

    });
});
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you show a sample response from the controller used as source?

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete being a widget implements the Widget Factory API by which you can extend its functionality ,one such extension point is the `_renderItem` .You can change how items are rendered.

Suppose your server returns sample data like this

```
$send =array(
        array( "label" => "javascript", "value" => "1" ,"img"=>"javascript.png"),
        array( "label" => "php", "value" => "2"  , "img"=>"php.ico" )
    );

echo json_encode($send);
```

i haven't written filtering part just for simplicity

Before initializing your autocomplete ovveride `_renderItem` by using widget factory API

```
$.widget( "app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var result = this._super( ul, item ); //get default functionality from parent
        if (item.img) {                       //if have image then add
            result.find( "a" )
                  .addClass( "ui-menu-item-icon" )
                  .css( "background-image", "url(" + item.img + ")" );
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

So when new data comes from the server instead it will call above code before rendering every option .`item` is the individual tuple in you json eg. for 3rd time item would be `{label: "python", value: "3" ,img: "python.png"}` so here we just add a background to `<li>` or `<a>` (preferable).`ul` is the list which jqueryui would add your custom entry to finally the `this._super( ul, item )` retrieves the parent (default) functionality , we just use this and modify it a little bit it's much like you subclass to make custom controls in GUI toolkit languages.

Now initialize

```
$( "#compnies_id" ).autocomplete({
       source: url+''+controller+'/'+country
});
```

That's all

Note that there is an alternative approach mentioned over [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) it's about returning an `<li>` (with whatever contents inside you need) and it would be used to show options, that works too but only problem with that is you would need to add ui classes (used for styling and accessibility by jqueryui) on those `<li>` yourself so your markup may end up looking

```
<li><a style="background-image: url(javascript.ico);">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
```

whereas it normally should be

```
 <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a class="ui-menu-item-icon ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-3" style="background-image: url(javascript.ico);">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
```

Jquery won't add those clases automatically for you when you are providing the `<li>`s

https://jsfiddle.net/ttnd0sp8/